# How to moq a Func

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq, func

Trying to unit test a class whose constructor takes in a Func. Not sure how to mock it using Moq.

```
public class FooBar
{
    public FooBar(Func<IFooBarProxy> fooBarProxyFactory)
    {
        _fooBarProxyFactory = fooBarProxyFactory;
    }
}



[Test]
public void A_Unit_Test()
{
    var nope = new Mock<Func<IFooBarProxy>>();
    var nope2 = new Func<Mock<IFooBarProxy>>();

    var fooBar = new FooBar(nope.Object);
    var fooBar2 = new FooBar(nope2.Object);

    // what's the syntax???
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

figured it out

```
public interface IFooBarProxy
{
    int DoProxyStuff();
}

public class FooBar
{
    private Func<IFooBarProxy> _fooBarProxyFactory;

    public FooBar(Func<IFooBarProxy> fooBarProxyFactory)
    {
        _fooBarProxyFactory = fooBarProxyFactory;
    }

    public int DoStuff()
    {
        var newProxy = _fooBarProxyFactory();
        return newProxy.DoProxyStuff();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Fixture
{
    [Test]
    public void A_Unit_Test()
    {
        Func<IFooBarProxy> funcFooBarProxy = () =>
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IFooBarProxy>();
            mock.Setup(x => x.DoProxyStuff()).Returns(2);
            return mock.Object;
        };
        var fooBar = new FooBar(funcFooBarProxy);

        var result = fooBar.DoStuff();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you've mocked the `Func` I think you are returning a mock object from a `Func`.

Comment: How do you set it up so that you can test a IFooBarProxy instance which will be returned when you call the Func in FooBar?

Comment: hey @Jon, I added a more complete answer, demonstrating how to do asserts on the mocked object. I hope that helps