# How do you create a Moq mock for a Func

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have the following Func method which i need to mock off

```
Func<Owned<ISomeInterface>> someMethod { get; set; }
```

but cant figure out how to mock it off using 'Moq' framework.

I have read a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036708/how-to-moq-a-func) on SO but still cant seem to mock it off, it always comes back with

> Expression is not a method invocation: x => Invoke(x.someMethod )

or

> A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the
>   mocked type.   ----> System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on
>   type 'Owned`1Proxy40a9bf91815d4658ad2453298c903652' not found.

Comment: I have read a related post on stackoverflow

Comment: Does that mean this question should be closed as a duplicate? Please clarify if this question is resolved..

Comment: sorry, the post did not seem to help me as it didn't work for me. I meant to edit the question but accidentally added a comment. I have now updated the question

Comment: why mock this Func? This is just a property and you can set it to any method which satisfies the signature and then call it, can't you?

Comment: @Helikaon, in my case, I wish to mock a sequence so the method returns different results when called multiple times. I'd also like to verify the number of times it is called.

Comment: Yes, but u have full control over ur delegate method implementation. What about if(callCount == 1) return value1; if(callCount==2) return value2; and u can closure a local callCount variable in ur test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Funct is defined as a property so you should use SetupSet within Moq

```
public interface IPersona
{
    string nome { get; set; }
    string cognome { get; set; }
    Func<Owned<ISomeInterface>> somemethod { get; set; }

}
```

. In your test :

You create a mock for the Func:

```
Func<Owned<ISomeInterface>> somemethodMock = () => new Mock<Owned<ISomeInterface>>().Object;
```

THen you setup the mock for the Class containing the Func as a property and you setup the expectation on the Set method :

```
var obj = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
obj.SetupSet(x => x.somemethod = somemethodMock).Verifiable();
```

You create the container object for the mock:

```
//We pass the mocked object to the constructor of the container class
var container = new Container(obj.Object);
container.AnotherMethod(somemethodMock);
obj.VerifyAll();
```

Here is the definition of Another method of the Container class, if get the func as an input parameter and set it to the property of the contained object

```
enter  public class Container
{
    private IPersona _persona;

    public Container(IPersona persona)
    {
        _persona = persona;
    }

    public void AnotherMethod(Func<MyClass<IMyInterface>> myFunc)
    {
        _persona.somemethod = myFunc;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked. I am now stuck on the very next line of the code lol where i have a static method being called from another assembly... will it ever end ;-)

Comment: That is painful :)  Have a look at this: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-mock-extension-methods/   it covers extension methods but it should fit considering they're static, hope it helps.

Comment: AutofacContrib.Moq.dll allows you to do a lot with Mocking off Funcs etc. and seems to have done the trick