# Using Moq to Mock a Func<> constructor parameter and Verify it was called twice

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, functional-testing

Taken the question from this article ([How to moq a Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036708/how-to-moq-a-func)) and adapted it as the answer is not correct.

```
public class FooBar
{
    private Func<IFooBarProxy> __fooBarProxyFactory;

    public FooBar(Func<IFooBarProxy> fooBarProxyFactory)
    {
        _fooBarProxyFactory = fooBarProxyFactory;
    }

    public void Process() 
    {
        _fooBarProxyFactory();
        _fooBarProxyFactory();
    }
}
```

I have a need to mock a Func<> that is passed as a constructor parameter, the assert that the func was call twice.

When trying to mock the function `var funcMock = new Mock<Func<IFooBarProxy>>();` Moq raises and exception as the Func type is not mockable.

The issue is that without mocking the func it is not possible to verify that the func was called (n) times. `funcMock.Verify( (), Times.AtLeast(2));`

Comment: Moq now supports what the OP was originally trying to do, see the answer from @ktam33

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to use a mock for the Func.

You can simply create an ordinary Func yourself that returns a mock of `IFooBarProxy`:

```
int numberOfCalls = 0;
Func<IFooBarProxy> func = () => { ++numberOfCalls;
                                  return new Mock<IFooBarProxy>(); };

var sut = new FooBar(func);

sut.Process();

Assert.Equal(2, numberOfCalls);
```

Comment: that does compile ??? should it  not be new Mock<IFooBarProxy>().Object ;-)

Comment: @HelloWorld This code is over 7 years old. Maybe Mock was changed since then? If you are sure how to correct it - please test it in real code - feel free to edit. As you can see from the other answers, Mock was indeed changed afterwards

Answer (score 43):

As of at least Moq 4.5.28, you can mock and verify the Func as you would expect to be able to. I couldn't tell when this feature was added (according to the original question at some point this did not work).

```
[Test]
public void TestFoobar()
{
    var funcMock = new Mock<Func<IFooBarProxy>>();
    var fooBar = new FooBar(funcMock.Object);
    fooBar.Process();
    funcMock.Verify(x => x(), Times.AtLeast(2));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Since Moq [v4.1.1308.2120](https://github.com/moq/moq4/releases/tag/v4.1.1308.2120)**

As of this version, which was released some months after this question was asked (Aug 21, 2013), the functionality to mock a `Func<>` [has been added](https://github.com/moq/moq4/commit/a35e953d286d1b27094e6f4dac45208116bffe87#diff-83b283b670610436e36bc3d91b9f3df5). So with any current version of mock, you can use `var funcMock = new Mock<Func<IFooBarProxy>>();`.

**Original (outdated) answer**

If you have a lot of callback `Func`'s, `Actions`, etc, it's better to define a helper interface in your tests and mock that interface. This way you can use the regular Moq functionality, like setting up return values, testing input arguments, etc.

```
interface IFooBarTestMethods
{
    IFooBarProxy FooBarProxyFactory();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var testMethodsMock = new Mock<IFooBarTestMethods>();
testMethodsMock
    .Setup(x => x.FooBarProxyFactory())
    .Returns(new Mock<IFooBarProxy>());

var sut = new FooBar(testMethodsMock.Object.FooBarProxyFactory);
testMethodsMock.Verify(x => x.FooBarProxyFactory(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Complex scenario like the below one

```
 public interface ISqlConnector
    {
        Task<int> ConnectAsync(Func<IDbConnection, Task<int>> performDatabaseOperationAsync, string connectionString);
    }
```

You can use

```
 var funcMock = new Mock<Func<IDbConnection,Task<int>>>();
            //setup Mock
            sqlConnector.Setup(a => a.ConnectAsync(funcMock.Object, It.IsAny<string>()));
```